# Adding Build number to the software

Tags: compiler-construction, ide, keil

Is there any way to add the build number in the code? (i mean the compiler/ide/other itself adds/maintains the build number in the code while compiling)? I want to display this build number for viewing (hence traceability of the code).

Does any one know how it can be achieved in keil software with tortoise svn?

Answer (score 2):

You can have your Makefile compute the build number (for example from source control tool) and then pass it from the Makefile to the compiler using `-D` option (for `gcc` for example):

```
gcc -DBUILD_NUMBER=\"$(BUILD_NUMBER)\" -c file.c
```

and then in your source file have something like this:

```
static const build_number[] = BUILD_NUMBER;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/), through its [keyword substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) facility, has the capability to write a build number into a source file when it is checked in.  I expect other source control systems have a similar feature.